# Jquery attr() multiple values

Tags: jquery, attr

I am using Checkboxes to Hide/Show items in a list.
Each item has a data-tag element containing one or more keywords.
Example

```
<li class="element" data-tag="business economic">
```

My JQuery currently look like this

```
$('.element').each(function(){
      var item = $(this).attr('data-tag');
      if(jQuery.inArray(itemarray,topic_list) > -1) 
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
      else
        $(this).hide();

    });
```

This works if there is a single element in data-tag, but if there is more than one, the LI elements are not displayed. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: you are not using `item`?

Comment: also what is `itemarray` and `topic_list`

Comment: use `$(this).data('tag')`

Comment: It should be item, sorry itemarray was a test, forgot to change

Comment: u can update your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `topic_list` is the string you search for inside the `data-tag` attribute:

```
jQuery('li[data-tag]').hide();  
jQuery('li[data-tag~="' + topic_list + '"]').fadeIn('slow');
```

EDIT

If `topic_list` is an array of tags:

```
jQuery('li[data-tag]').hide();
for(var i = 0, l = topic_list.length; i < l; i++) {
  var tag = topic_list[i];
  jQuery('li[data-tag~="' + tag + '"]').fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Comment: This seems to get close but If Business and Economic are both checked, none are displayed. is my updated code `$('.element').each(function(){
      $('li[data-tag]').hide();  
      $('li[data-tag~=' + topic_list + ']').fadeIn('slow');

    }); `

Comment: ok this is of easy solution, but when both are checked which is the value of `topic_list`? is it an array `['business', 'economic']` or a string `business economic`?

Comment: also get an error when both are checked `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: li[data-tag~=business,economic]`

Comment: see error message above, topic_list is set this way above the code `var topic_list = []; $('.element :input:checked').each(function(){
        var topic = $(this).val();
        topic_list.push(topic); //Push each check item's value into an array
      });`

Comment: error message fixed by adding quotes  `$('li[data-tag~="' + topic_list + '"]').fadeIn('slow');` still have the issue of none displayed if 2 check boxes checked

Comment: to respond to your question, when both are checked, it is an array that is returned, ie ["business", "economic"]

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.element').each(function(){
  var tags = $(this).data('tag');
  if(tags.contains(topic_list)) 
    $(this).fadeIn('slow');
  else
    $(this).hide();

});
```

Comment: business, economic etc are dynamically generated and I wont know what they are